# Is there a PyQt table/ listview that can be filled dynamically with comboboxes in one of the columns?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qgis

I'm using PyQt for a qgis plugin. I'd like to have some sort of table/ listview with the first column being layers from the open shapefile, then the second column being comboboxes that will be loaded with values from a database input. Is this possible and if so do I need to use listview, tableview, or treeview? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correct understood you, I've done something quite similar a while ago.

In my case I wanted to populate the following QTableWidget with QDoubleSpinBoxes and set specific properties for each of them.

[image]

So I made a "model" empty QTableWidget in QDesigner and in my code I used the following function:

## Populate QTableWidget

```
def QTableWidget_populate(self, table):
    # Create an empty matrix with the same dimensions as your table
    self.ele_mat = [
        [0 for x in range(table.columnCount())] for x in range(table.rowCount())]
    # For each cell in the table define its characteristics
    for row in xrange(table.rowCount()):
        for column in xrange(table.columnCount()):
            # Define row name prefix
            if row == 0:
                element = 'Begin_'
            elif row == 1:
                element = 'MidMinus_'
            elif row == 2:
                element = 'MidPlus_'
            elif row == 3:
                element = 'End_'

            # Define columns paraters
            if column == 0:
                element += 'Pow'    # Name column sufix
                param1 = '2'        # setDecimals settings
                param2 = '-99,99'   # setRange
                param3 = '"dBm"'    # seSuffix
            elif column == 1:
                element += 'PD'
                param1 = '0'
                param2 = '0,999'
                param3 = '"uA"'
            elif column == 2:
                element += 'TMVoltage'
                param1 = '2'
                param2 = '-99,99'
                param3 = '"V"'
            elif column == 3:
                element += 'Wav'
                param1 = '1'
                param2 = '0,2000'
                param3 = '"nm"'
            # Popule matrix with dict of parameters
            self.ele_mat[row][column] = {
                'name': element, 'type': 'QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()',
                                         'Adjustments': ['setDecimals', 'setRange', 'setSuffix'],
                                         'Params':  [param1, param2, param3]}
    # Using the matrix populate the QTableWidget                                  
    for row in xrange(table.rowCount()):
        for column in xrange(table.columnCount()):
            # Create Widget with name and type defined in the matrix
            exec('self.{} = {}' .format(
                self.ele_mat[row][column]['name'],
                self.ele_mat[row][column]['type']))

            # Give it its settings
            for adjustment, param in zip(self.ele_mat[row][column]['Adjustments'],
                                         self.ele_mat[row][column]['Params']):
                exec('self.{}.{}({})' .format(self.ele_mat[
                     row][column]['name'], adjustment, param))

            # Set the created widget to the QTableWidget
            table.setCellWidget(row, column, eval(
                'self.{}' .format(self.ele_mat[row][column]['name'])))

    # For better clarity in GUI
    table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

I don't know exactly how is the format from the file you are reading but I'm sure you can add a `for` loop inside my function to setValue to the QDoubleSpinBox according to entries in your file. Furthermore, you can set the Header Labels via code as well using the `setVerticalHeaderLabels` and `setHorizontalHeaderLabels`methods.

Even though I use pyqt, I generally use pyside's documentation because they are most of the times equal and pyside's is much easier to read and navigate through.
[QTableWidget Docs](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget)

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @InsertDisplayName ... then you could accept the answer, no ?